# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The new session command returned a value ('Unknown error') that is not a valid JSON object

Tags: c#, json, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver

#### Introductions

I am developing an application that uses different types and versions of selenium libraries.

The goal of the application is to run Microsoft Edge and the value of the parameter associated with the EdgeDriver class is to navigate to the URL.

---

#### Problem

When running the application in the IDE (JetBrains Rider), an error occurs even though Microsoft Edge was running correctly.

---

#### Error

```
[19:56:40.601] - Listening on http://127.0.0.1:20082/
[19:56:40.601] - Listening on http://[::1]:20082/
Unhandled exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The new session command returned a value ('Unknown error') that is not a valid JSON object.
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver..ctor(EdgeDriverService service, EdgeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver..ctor(EdgeDriverService service, EdgeOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver..ctor(EdgeOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver..ctor()
   at WebRequest_Login.InstagramSelenium.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Alexx\RiderProjects\WebRequest-Login\WebRequest-Login\Program.cs:line 191
```

---

#### Source Code

```
    EdgeDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
    
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("Instagram.com");
    
    IWebElement usernameInput = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='username']"));
    IWebElement passwordInput = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='password']"));
    
    
    usernameInput.SendKeys("YourUsername");
    passwordInput.SendKeys("YourPassword");
```

---

#### NuGet Libraries / Packages

`Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver` - Version `87.0.669`

`Selenium.WebDriver` - Version `4.0.0-alpha07`

Comment: Which version of Edge are you using?